# VBA, Find function doesn't find the input

Tags: vba, find

I have cells with dates in format dd.mm.yyyy and would like to keep only the rows, where column A contains the date, entered with input box, the other should be deleted.

I just can't figure it out, why the find function doesn't find the input. I've tried with the exact date instead of AddDate and it does't work, so I'm guessing  the problem is in the format?

Please help. This is the part of the code:

```
Dim AddDate As String

AddDate = InputBox("Enter date for export.", "Enter date", "DD.MM.YYYY")
          
Dim FoundRange As Range

Set FoundRange = Range("A:A").Find(what:=AddDate, LookIn:=xlValue, lookat:=xlWhole)
   If FoundRange Is Nothing Then
   MsgBox "Date not found. Use the correct format DD.MM.YYYY."
   Workbooks("KOREN.xlsm").Close
   GoTo The_End
Else

Dim i As Long
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   With Worksheets("KOREN")
      For i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 3 Step -1
        Select Case LCase(.Cells(i, 1).Value)
            Case AddDate
                'do nothing
            Case Else
                .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End Select
      Next i
   End With
Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
```

Comment: some sample data would help

Answer (score 0):

Finally, got it.

I added

```
If Not Format(AddDate, "DD.MM.YYYY") = AddDate Then
        MsgBox "Wrong format. Use DD.MM.YYYY."
        GoTo ReEnter
```

to input box and set FoundRange to find DateValue

```
set FoundRange = Range("A:A").Find(what:=DateValue(AddDate), LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlWhole)
```